# TypeScript won't let me manipulate RX JS res

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need a quick fix for this issue(Angular 4):

```
 title:string;
 content: string;
  comment: string;

  constructor( private http: HttpClient) {}

  posts: {title: string, content: string, comments: String[]}[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3003/posts').subscribe( res => {
      console.log(res))
      // can't do res.forEach (object has no forEach)
      // can't do JSON.parse(res) because res is not a string

  })
}
```

The content of res:

```
["{"title":"sadsa","content":"sadasd","comments":[]}", "{"title":"sadsa","content":"sadasd","comments":[]}", "{"title":"sadsa","content":"sadasd","comments":[]}", "{"title":"sadsa","content":"sadasd","comments":[]}", "{"title":"sadsa","content":"sadasd","comments":[]}", "{"title":"sadsa","content":"sadasd","comments":[]}", "{"title":"sadsa","content":"sadasd","comments":[]}"]
```

I send an array from my server that is like an array I have on client, the problem is, it comes in a format of stringified array, but from some reason, the type script won't let me handle it like an array, claiming it to be an object, I tried to send an object which would contain the array, but then it claims 'unresolved variable'.
what am I missing in all this?

Comment: Can you show what's the content of `res`?

Comment: I added it to the post, couldn't format it to be multiple lines though... its basically an array of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is not a proper json object. Use following code to get proper json:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3003/posts').subscribe( (res: any[]) => {
      console.log(res))
      let data = res.map(d => {
        return JSON.parse(d);
      });
      // data will be an array of data. Assign it to a property of component.

    })
  }
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: TypeScript won't compile, expecting res to be some sort of object(not the array type)

Answer (score 2):

The response is of type [Response](https://angular.io/api/http/Response). You can call `res.json()` on it to get at the contents. No, this is not documented in the reference page because google hates you.

Comment: I knew it! this is what I get for using their angular!

Comment: Jokes aside, 'Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.'

Answer (score 1):

Using Angular `Http` you can map the response before you subscribe to the Request, like so:

```
...
ngOnInit() {
   this.http.get('http://localhost:3003/posts')
       .map(toJsonFn)  // or map to you class or what have you
       .subscribe( res => {
           console.log(res))
       })
}

toJsonFn(res: Response){
    return res.json();
}
...
```

Note that you may have to import the `map` operator from rxjx - `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`

Also Note that if you use [Angular 5 `HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-request-for-json-data) the Response will automatically be parsed as json for you.

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked as well, its the ultimate good solution.